# JavaScript: Extract first letter of every string in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substr

I'm quite new in coding, so might be an easy question for you all.
What exactly should I do if I have this array and want to just show the first letter of every element of it?

```
var friends = ["John", "Will", "Mike"];
```

I wanted to do it with `substr` method but I just want to know how to do it with a string.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: This is a question I would give someone learning JavaScript and I would except that person to perform some research to come to a solution. I advise the same for you. hint: loops and substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the array, take the 1st letter using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and return it:

```js
const friends = ["John", "Will", "Mike"];
const result = friends.map(([v])=> v);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does these => operators stand for?

Comment: ES6 arrow functions

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else is using new fancy ECMAScript6 I'll give the oldschool version of it:

```js
var friends = ["John", "Will", "Mike"];

for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
  console.log(friends[i][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use loop for that array and access the first character using `charAt(0)`

```js
var friends = ["John", "Will", "Mike"];
friends.forEach((name)=>{
  console.log(name.charAt(0));
});
```

> charAt() method returns a new string consisting of the single UTF-16 code unit located at the specified offset into the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` to create array of first letters like:

```
let firstLetters = friends.map(s => s[0]);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let friends = ["John", "Will", "Mike"];

let firstLetters = friends.map(s => s[0]);

console.log(firstLetters);
```

---

Alternatively you can use String's `.charAt()` method:

```
let firstLetters = friends.map(s => s.charAt(0));
```

**Demo:**

```js
let friends = ["John", "Will", "Mike"];

let firstLetters = friends.map(s => s.charAt(0));

console.log(firstLetters);
```

---

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`String.prototype.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

Comment: sweet! and what about showing just the last letter of every element? is it possible to do it with the same .map and/or charAt method?

Comment: @Pepdbm7 Yes, just use `string.length - 1` as index. For example `friends.map(s => s[s.length - 1]);` or with charAt() like `friends.map(s => s.charAt(s.length - 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Know something about [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var friends = ["John", "Will", "Mike"];
console.log(friends.map(v=>v[0]))
```